# How to achieve check box and text field dependency in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, smarty

I'm using PHP, Smarty, jQuery, etc. for my website. Now the scenario is in one template file there is some code containing loops, checkboxes, textfields, etc. For your reference I'm putting the necessary code snippet from smarty template as below:

```
{foreach from=$subject_topic_data.topics item=topic_diff_level_data}
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_topics[]" value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}">
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="middle">        
                                <p class="custom-form">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" name="{$sheet_type}_topics_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}[]" id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}" value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}"  {if in_array($topic_diff_level_data.topic_id, $practice_sheet_set_details[$subject_topic_data.subject_id].topics)}checked="checked"{/if}>
                                <label>{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_name}</label>
                                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="topic_names[{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}]" value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_name}">   -->
                                </p>                   
                              </td>
                              {foreach from=$topic_diff_level_data.difficulty_level item=diff_level key=key_diff_lvl}
                              <td valign="middle">                 
                              {if $site_id=='ENTPRM'}<em>Total {$diff_level.question_count}</em>{/if}
                                <input type="text" name="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}"  maxlength="3" class="mini" value="{$diff_level.added_no_questions}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="{$sheet_type}_available_questions_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" value="{$diff_level.question_count}">
                              </td>
                              {/foreach}               
                            </tr>
                            {/foreach}
```

Now from the above code what I want to achieve is when the user checks the check box of subject the concerned topic text fields should get enabled. Initially when the page loads all the tesxtfields of all the topics should be disabled. CAn you help me in achieving this? If you want some additional information I can provide you the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `topic text fields should get enabled` where is the disabled input? Suggestion : please put the generated html that would help lot better.

Comment: client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side:**

```
{foreach from=$subject_topic_data.topics item=topic_diff_level_data}
<input type="hidden" 
        name="subject_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_topics[]" 
        value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}">
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">        
        <p class="custom-form">
```

checkbox: give id of `subject_selected`

```
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-check" 
            name="{$sheet_type}_topics_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}[]" 
            id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}" 
            value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}"  
            {if in_array($topic_diff_level_data.topic_id,
            $practice_sheet_set_details[$subject_topic_data.subject_id].topics)}checked="checked"{/if}>
        //disabled
        <label>{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_name}</label>

        <!-- <input type="hidden" 
                    name="topic_names[{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}]" 
                    value="{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_name}">  
        -->
        </p>                   
    </td>
    {foreach from=$topic_diff_level_data.difficulty_level item=diff_level key=key_diff_lvl}
        <td valign="middle">                 
            {if $site_id=='ENTPRM'}<em>Total {$diff_level.question_count}</em>{/if}
            <input type="text" 
                    name="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" 
                id="{$sheet_type}_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}"  
                maxlength="3" class="mini" value="{$diff_level.added_no_questions}">
            <input type="hidden" 
                name="{$sheet_type}_available_questions_{$subject_topic_data.subject_id}_{$topic_diff_level_data.topic_id}_{$key_diff_lvl}" 
                value="{$diff_level.question_count}">
        </td>
   {/foreach}               
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function subject_selection(/* pass the selection here */){
    var check= document.getElementById('subject_selection');
    if (check.checked){
```

> /*  if checked, ajax? change html values(ie hidden)? that's up to you  */
>   **or**
>   document.getElementById('inputSelected').type = "" /* change it accordingly */

```
    }
}
```